Path redirection not working when website is deployed to Vercel, error 404
I have a website deployed to text which is connected to the repository text. The issue here is that Vercel works perfectly until you click any link in the navbar (except for 'Oscar Rodriguez').
All those links where supposed to redirect the person from https://oscar-rodriguez.vercel.app/ to https://oscar-rodriguez.vercel.app/inProcess.html. It worked when testing on localhost but now I noticed my little understanding of Vercel.
I hope somebody finds the solution, and thanks in advance !
For you to not get lost among so many files, I moved inProcess.html inside the public folder, but that didn´t do the trick either. If you have any concern or advice regarding to the project, please contact me.

You hardcoded the href values in your /src/Components/Nav.tsx component.
For example:
<a target="_blank" href="https://oscar-r-s.github.io">About</a>

To fix it, use a relative path like this:
<a target="_blank" href="/about">About</a>

